# Ajax Call: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to connect to my database using ajax calls and php to create a chart using google chart api, but I am getting an error of "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" and I have no idea what to do. This is my ajax call

```
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
        }).responseText;
```

and this is my php file

```
<?php
    $host = "host = 127.0.0.1";
    $port = "port = 5432";
    $dbname = "dbname = postgres";
    $credentials = "user = postgres password = 1111";

    $db = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials");

    if(!$db) {
        echo "Error: Unable to open database\n";
    } else {
        echo "Opened database successfully\n";
    }

    $sql =<<< EOF
        SELECT * FROM us;
    EOF;

    $ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
    if(!$ret) {
        echo pg_last_error($db);
        exit;
    } 

    echo "{ \"cols\": [ {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Month\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"date\"}, {\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Number of Coronavirus Cases\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"} ], \"rows\": [ ";

    while($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)) {
        echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['covid_date'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $row['cases'] . ",\"f\":null}]}";
    }

    echo " ] }";
?>
```

Comment: That simply means your php code is not reponding with a json object. From my experience, I think there might be some errors occurring in your php code, and your are responding error markup (as your response starts with <) instead of a json response.

Comment: Don't create JSON manually. Use `json_encode()`